# Replace attribute terms with wp_update_term (woocommerce)

Tags: php, terms

On the edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes page I want to replace (when I import a product via my importer plugin) the term name of the Terms attribute with a new name.

[image]

For example: if the name 'Old Name' exists as (term) change it to 'New Name'

I used the code:

```
$nname = 'New Name';
wp_update_term(69, '1display', 
  array(
    '‎Old Name' => $nname,
    'slug' => sanitize_title($nname)
  )
);
```

but it was unsuccessful, it didn't work.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you

Re:
I also tried this but it doesn't work... what am I doing wrong? Thank you

```
$your_term = get_term_by( 'Old Name', 'old-name' );

if ( false !== $your_term ) {
    wp_update_term( 69, 'Old Name', $args = array('Old Name' => 'New Name' ));
    global $wpdb;
}
```